# Create object using parameters pack in template

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, variadic-templates, smart-pointers

I'd like to create template function that would create object basing on template typename and parameters pack.

I created a function that is supposed to create object based on typename from template, and I would also like to pass parameters pack to that template i order to pass parameters to constructor. Is this correct?:

```
template<typename TComponent, typename... Args>
    void CreateComponent(Args... args) 
    {
        std::shared_ptr<TComponent> component = std::make_shared<TComponent>(args ...);
    }
```

I also wanted to pass those parameters to another fucntion like this:

```
template<typename TComponent, typename... Args>
    void AddComponent(Args... args) 
    {
          m_world->AddComponent<TComponent, Args>(m_id, args...);
    }
```

But compiler returns an error " 'args' parameter pack must be expanded in this context"

Is it even possible to achieve what I want to achieve ?

Comment: With perfect forwarding: `template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void CreateComponent(Args&&... args) 
    {
        auto component = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But compiler returns an error " 'args' parameter pack must be expanded in this context"

Yes: you've forgotten to expand the types

```
m_world->AddComponent<TComponent, Args...>(m_id, args...);
// ...................................^^^
```

As pointed by Jarod42, according to the circumstances, you could avoid to explicit the `Args...` expansion

```
m_world->AddComponent<TComponent>(m_id, args...);
// no more Args...
```

and let the compiler deduce the types through `args...` (but we should see the `AddComponent()` definition).

Anyway, I don't see errors in your `CreateComponents()` function but, as correctly says François Andrieux in a comment, you don't using perfect forwarding.

It's a too-great argument to explain in an answer but, this way, you're renouncing to move semantics advantages (that is: you, potentially, make some unnecessary copies).

The following is your `CreateComponents()` function enabling perfect forwarding

```
template <typename TComponent, typename ... Args>
void CreateComponent (Args && ... args) 
 { // .....................^^ forwarding reference added
   std::shared_ptr<TComponent> component
     = std::make_shared<TComponent>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 } // ..............................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `, Args...` can probably be omitted as deduced.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - yes; I've added something. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, gotcha! Thanks for your help !